# Can't run IDEA 14 on Ubuntu 14

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, intellij-idea

When I run Idea from `idea.sh`, I get this error:

```
'tools.jar' seems to be not in IDEA classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.
```

My actual $JAVA_HOME is

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_60
```

Inside it I've got, navigating through folders, the `tools.jar`.
If I run `java -version` I get this output:

```
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and trying to run IDEA 141.1532.4.

I've also added `/opt/idea-IC-141.1532.4/bin` to my $PATH variable, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You may perhaps wish to take a look at these solutions, http://askubuntu.com/questions/122133/tools-jar-is-not-in-idea-classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and select the JDK rather than the JRE.